# Algebra Confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the problem below how did they get the final expression?

It looks like they subtracted a $7$ from $64$, but in all honesty I am lost on how they ended up with the final expression.

$$
\begin{aligned}
7^{(k+1)+2}+8^{2(k+1)+1} &=7^{k+3}+8^{2 k+3} \\
&=7 \cdot 7^{k+2}+8^{2} \cdot 8^{2 k+1} \\
&=7 \cdot 7^{k+2}+64 \cdot 8^{2 k+1} \\
&=7\left(7^{k+2}+8^{2 k+1}\right)+57 \cdot 8^{2 k+1}
\end{aligned}
$$

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk3mk.png)

Comment: Was this from a proof by induction that $7^{n+2}+8^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $57$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $64\cdot8^{2k+1}=7\cdot8^{2k+1}+57\cdot8^{2k+1}$:

$7\cdot7^{k+2}+\color{blue}{64\cdot8^{2k+1}}=7\cdot7^{k+2}+\color{blue}{7\cdot8^{2k+1}+57\cdot8^{2k+1}}=7(7^{k+2}+8^{2k+1})+57\cdot8^{2k+1}$